# Prettier - new line between function and comment

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I would like to know if there's a rule to add a new line between function/statement and comment in typescript with prettier (.prettierrc at the root of the project).

Current behaviour:

```js
 } else if (request.type === 'membership-fee') {
    /**
     * If type is membership fee
     */
    this.form.get('total')?.setValue(this.gym?.membership_fee?.total);
} else {
    /**
     * Operation type not recognized
     */
    this.toast.error('Tipo di operazione non riconosciuto');
    ($('#editSaleModal') as any).modal('hide');
}
```

Desired behaviour:

```js
 } else if (request.type === 'membership-fee') {
    
    /**
     * If type is membership fee
     */
    this.form.get('total')?.setValue(this.gym?.membership_fee?.total);
} else {
    
    /**
     * Operation type not recognized
     */
    this.toast.error('Tipo di operazione non riconosciuto');
    ($('#editSaleModal') as any).modal('hide');
}
```

My current .prettierc:

```json
{
    "useTabs": true,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "printWidth": 120
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, prettier doesn't have that rule.

Prettier has a sparse [list of options by design](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html), and this isn't one of'm.

Comment: So I have no choice but to see my new lines disappear every time I "Format Document" with vscode?

Comment: Well, technically, you have the choice not to use prettier, if the rules it has aren't what you want / need, @IanFarré.

Comment: Well yeah, but I wanted to use prettier since it accepts many file formats and it's a good standard for my webdev projects. But everything comes with it's tradeoffs i guess. Do you know any good code formatters to use in a TS/HTML/SCSS project?

Comment: No, I use prettier, myself, @IanFarré

Comment: It's important to understand is that the whole point of prettier is you're supposed to get over your need to use your special styles of writing JS and instead just use a standard. Not to judge your idea, because a fun thing about JS is you can experiment with styles you like in your own code. For everyone working together on JS it's good for us  have a single standard though.

Answer (score 1):

But you can achive this behavior with ESLint:

[image]

And automaticly fix this issue for example on save in VSCode:

[image]

Check this rule  for ESLinter. [lines-around-comment](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/newline-before-return)

ESLinter gives you tonns of benefits.

Comment: Honestly I didn't think it could act as a formatter with it's --fix flag but I think I will stick with prettier since it formats many different files with the same rules.